# no visible @interface for xxxx declares

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to learn obj-c and the thing is, following a tutorial, I found out myself with 
"no visible @interface for CardGameViewer declares the selector 'titleForCard'" and
"no visible @interface for CardGameViewer declares the selector 'backgroundImageForCard'"
I dont get it. Is it because the "self" may not ref the good thing?

Thanks in advance.

```
//CardGameViewController.m

#import "CardGameViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"

@interface CardGameViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic)Deck *deck;
@property (strong, nonatomic)CardMatchingGame *game;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@end

@implementation CardGameViewController


-(Deck *)createDeck{
    return [[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init];
}

-(CardMatchingGame *)game{
    if(!_game) _game= [[CardMatchingGame alloc]initWitchCardCount:[self.cardButtons count] usingDeck:[self createDeck]];
    return _game;
}


- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    int cardIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender];
    [self.game chooseCardAtIndex:cardIndex];
    [self updateUI];
}

-(void)updateUI{
    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons){
        int cardIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton];
        Card *card= [self.game cardAtIndex:cardIndex];
        [cardButton setTitle:**[self titleForCard]** forState:(UIControlStateNormal)]; //ERROR HERE
        [cardButton setBackgroundImage:**[self backgroundImageForCard]** forState: (UIControlStateNormal)]; //ERROR HERE
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isMatched;
    }
}

- (NSString *)titleForCard:(Card *)card{
    return card.isChosen ? card.contents : @"";
}

- (UIImage *)backgroundImageForCard:(Card *)card{
    return [UIImage imageNamed:card.isChosen ? @"cardFront" : @"cardBack"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods have parameters.

You should use them like:

```
[cardButton setTitle:[self titleForCard:card] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
[cardButton setBackgroundImage:[self backgroundImageForCard:card] forState: (UIControlStateNormal)];
```

P.S: self is quite good since you're declaring these methods in "self".